# Event after jqueryui sortable finished sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to trigger a callback function after the sorting of jqueryuis sortable completely finished and everything is in place again.

I tried the `stop` event, but the element I dragged is still positioned absolute, so this is not what I want.

Is there any event to achieve that, or do I need to set up some weird timeout stuff?

Comment: did you try update event ? http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an update method. You can write your code in update method.

```
update: function(event, ui) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and change your id accordingly

```
var sortableFormList = document.getElementById("editDynamicSpace");
new Sortable(sortableFormList, {
    animation: 150,
    handle: ".card-header",
    ghostClass: 'blue-background-class',
    onEnd: function(e) {
        // write steps which you want to perform after sorting
    }
```